# Combine 2 or more mov/avi files side-by-side?

Tags: video, editing

I have several cameras that capture multiple viewpoints of the same location. I want to show the views side-by-side so that we can see what happened from all the angles at one time.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10 and willing to try anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239939/ffmpeg-how-to-play-2-flvs-next-to-each-other-in-1-flv/4240140#4240140