# What video editing programme is capable of placing two videos side by side?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor

I would like to show the left half of the first video on the left, and the right half of the second on the right.

Are there any programmes that offer this feature, or is there a workaround anyone can think of?

Comment: This probably is a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46070/combine-2-or-more-mov-avi-files-side-by-side

Comment: I only wanted half of each video, not the full thing.

Comment: You are right, I misread your question, sorry about that ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### OpenShot

[image]

- Place clips on two separate tracks.
- Right click first video and choose *Layout 1/4 Size - Top Left*
- Right click second video and choose *Layout 1/4 Size - Top Right*
- Right click first video and choose *Show All (Maintain Ratio)*

Answer (score 2):

You can try shotcut (http://shotcut.org/bin/view/Shotcut). It comes with the posibility for video compositing. Just like in Openshot you can include one video on track and another on another track. Then you will enable to composite option on the left side of each track. Now you can apply on each the filter "resize" and put each video in it's place on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenShot. This method is slightly longer than previous answers, but it will remove the black bars at the top and bottom of the screen.

1. Create two tracks, and place the one clip in each track.
2. Go to the top and open the profiles menu:  *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Profiles*.
3. Click on *Manage profiles*, and create a new profile that is the side of both videos placed next to each other, and with the correct aspect ratio.
4. Go back to the main screen, and for each track <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the clip, and then select the *Video* tab. Then set the horizontal alignment to be either left or right, depending on the track. Then apply changes.
5. When you go to export the video, make sure to use your custom profile.

Answer (score 1):

[Gridplayer](https://github.com/vzhd1701/gridplayer) does the trick.  Other options would not accept videos of differing resolutions.

- Reference: https://connectwww.com/play-multiple-videos-side-by-side-with-gridplayer/63407/